# Getting differences between two lists (not just comparison)

Tags: python

The following code is listing the difference between two lists:

```
def Diff(li1, li2):
    return list(set(li1) - set(li2)) + list(set(li2) - set(li1))

ListA = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
ListB= ["A","B","X"];

diff = Diff(ListA , ListB)
print(diff )
```

Output

```
['D', 'E', 'C', 'X']
```

but what I need is not just listing the differences, what I need is:

A) list only Items from List A where are not listed in List B
B) list only Items from List B where are not listed in List A

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to understand what *your* `Diff` function actually does and how exactly. Then your A and B will be come quite trivial.

Comment: Oh wow! this was very helpful!

Comment: he's trying to say change your plus to a comma, but I agree, why not learn what the code is actually doing first?  Specifically why adding two lists would result in one list.

Comment: Can you include expected results as an example looking like your actual results? Do you want 2 lists?

Comment: It sounds kinda like you want two different functions for doing these two different things, or maybe one function that returns two different lists,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code list what you need but in one list

A) list only Items from List A where are not listed in List B

```
InANotInB=list(set(li1) - set(li2))
```

B) list only Items from List B where are not listed in List A

```
InBNotInA=list(set(li2) - set(li1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your lists can contain duplicate elements, you will need to use `Counter` instead of `set`:

```
from collections import Counter
def diff(L1,L2):
    C1,C2 = Counter(L1),Counter(L2)
    return list((C1-C2).elements()), list((C2-C1).elements())
```

Output:

```
ListA = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
ListB= ["A","B","X"]

print(diff(ListA ,ListB))

(['C', 'D', 'E'], ['X'])   # (Only in listA, Only in ListB)

ListA = ["A","B","B","B","C","D","E"]
ListB= ["A","A","X","B","C","C","C"]

print(diff(ListA ,ListB))

(['B', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'X', 'C', 'C'])
```

If you only need a single list of elements that are not in both lists:

With Counter to support duplicates:

```
def diff(L1,L2):
    C1,C2 = Counter(L1),Counter(L2)
    return [*((C1|C2)-(C1&C2)).elements() ]

# ['C', 'D', 'E', 'X']
# ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'X']
```

Using sets if lists don't contain duplicates:

```
def diff(L1,L2):
    return set(L1).symmetric_difference(L2)

# {'D', 'X', 'E', 'C'}
```